# Moving AppData folders does not delete original data

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, disk-space

To free up `C:\` disk space, I had decided to move `AppData\Local`, `AppData\LocalLow` and `AppData\Roaming` folders to `D:\AppData\`. The moving was successful – `%appdata%` links to `D:\AppData\Roaming\`.
Everything seems to be okay, except for the files left in `C:\Users\User\Appdata\`. They were not deleted. When I tried to delete these folders manually, the message appeared that the folder had been in use by another program.
How can I get rid of ghost folders left in `C:\Users\User\Appdata\`?

Comment: How exactly did you move this folder?  You should be specific when you update your question.

Answer (score 2):

1. There are [junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) in user profile. When you move folders using Explorer, it does weird things with them, breaking junctions and moving files to unexpected paths (followed by junctions), and then not placing them where they must be.
   To avoid troubles, only move using some junction-aware software. I recommend [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html). In recent versions of command line utility `ln.exe` (from same site), there is `-b` switch for copying whole directory (like a user profile) preserving permissions and updating internal symlinks&junctions (they'll point to new location).
2. AppData contains many significant Windows folders, including Start Menu, Win+X menu shortcuts, Send To, etc. Many of them are in use when user is logged on. Also, since Windows 8 there is One Drive executable in `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive`. Some other programs also put their executables to `%APPDATA%`. Running executables and files-in-use cannot be deleted (or moved to another volume).
   Because of all that, you better create another (temporary) user, add it to Administrators group, log off from account you're moving, log in via temporary account, and then move whole profile or specific folders.
   After that you can log on back under original account, and remove temporary account and its profile.
3. IMO it's better to either

   - only move specific *user* folders (Documents, Video, etc; not AppData)
     or
   - create new profiles in right place instead of moving them as whole. You can edit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`:`ProfilesDirectory` and set it to folder you want to be base for new profiles.
4. Since Windows 8, you have to have correct permissions for *Universal* (aka Modern, aka Metro, aka AppX) apps to be working. Since Windows 10, this also applies to Start menu (if permissions are incorrect, Start menu won't open at all!). So you have to move profile with permissions, or copy permissions afterwards (using something like SetACL, see at [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-copy-a-directory-with-all-permissions-and/373353a9-7bc2-468e-ac20-04850c105e3f))
5. In Win10 ver. 1607 (10.0.14393) there is strange bug breaking Start Menu for all users if you mess with permissions of one (even for admins, even when messing with non-admin profile). In my case, it reproduces reliably when taking ownership for all folders of any loaded profile (even non-admin). Even more strangely, fix is to interactively log in with a user without profile (either new or existing one), and let Windows create the profile. Start menu starts working right away for all users. Afterwards new profile and user can be removed, or can be used normally. In older version and current Insider Preview builds this does not reproduce.